# How to generate the diagnostic regression plots of rbase to an object that is not a lm class?

Tags: r, plot, regression, radix, lm

I would like to generate the regression diagnostic plots from the base of **r**, to a 'non-lm' object.

```
## Generate reg. with lm function
set.seed(2458840)
x <- runif(10) 
y <- x + rnorm(10,0,1)
lm1 <- lm(y~x)
plot(lm1)

## Generate a regression with plm
library(plm)
data("Gasoline", package = "plm")
Gasoline <- plm.data(Gasoline, c("country","year"))
lm2 <- plm(lgaspcar ~ lincomep + lrpmg + lcarpcap, data = Gasoline, effect = 'twoways', model = 'within')
# Not working
plot(lm2)
```

Comment: I think it will take some hacking. I tried setting the class to `lm`, `lm3 = lm2; class(lm3) = "lm"` and then plotting, but it seem the object is deficient in some attributes. I get `Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute`. You could try to add an appropriate `terms` attribute, cross you fingers and see what the next problem is, or you could try to roll your own plots.

Comment: I don't think that would work. My best shot so far is trying to see what is inside the methods for the plot function. For instance, 'methods(plot)', prints all the methods, there is one labeled 'plot.lm*', but I don't know how to get the code inside.

Comment: Type `stats:::plot.lm` in the console to see the code. (Note that there are 6 available diagnostic plots, but the default is to only show 4.) It could work depending on what parts of the object it needs to access. Writing a `terms.plm` would be a start.